# RegEX to get the required field from a string in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, parsing, sh

I got a String as below.

`report="Reading trace file coverage/lcov.info Summary coverage rate: lines......: 80.5% (4900 of 6090 lines) functions..: no data"
echo The value of variable = $report`

Add I want to parse only "80.5" in this and store in a shell Script variable.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Im new to shell scripting and 
tried 
parse1="$(cut -d':' -f2 <<<"$report")" and 
$ awk '{split($0, a, ":"); print a[2]}' <<< $report
but didn't get the proper out put

Comment: @Uday : Please add your solution by editing your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
[[ "$report" =~ :\ ([0-9.]+)% ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This regular expression (`:\ ([0-9.]+)%`) describes a substring that contains a colon followed by a space, then comes at least one character that is a number or a dot (`[0-9.]+`), and then comes a percent sign. The part that matches between round brackets is taken into field 1 of array BASH_REMATCH.

Output:

```
80.5
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Bingo!! this works, can you explain the regEx, it will help others too in understanding the regEX.

Comment: @Uday: I have completed my answer.